# Driver Install Fails Because Cross Signing Chain doesn't contain microsoft

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, code-signing

Do you know why "Microsoft Code Verification Root" would be missing from a signing certificate chain?

We recently moved a build system between two domains and had to re-install certs.  We found that we had a signing problem where Microsoft wasn't in the chain causing kernel driver rejection during install.

We noticed that we had 2 additional certs in  certmgr : Trusted Publisher : Certificates

- Class 3 Public Primary Certification..
- Verisign Class 3 Code Signing...

After disabling **Class 3 Public Primary Certification** the "problem" went away and we have the proper signing chain with Microsoft on top.

I'm not sure how **Class 3 Public Primary Certification** was installed or what we using it and am testing to see what impacts we might face.

Has anyone run into this kind of problem and how did they approach it?  Is there a way to disable the use of the class-3 on the command line so I can leave the certmgr setting alone thereby reducing risk ?

Thanks for the help

Peter

**Sign Command**

```
signtool.exe sign /v /ac MSCV-VSClass3.cer /s TrustedPublisher /n "My Corp" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll mydriver.sys
```

**Sign Verification**
    signtool verify /kp /v mydriver.sys

```
*** Signing Certificate Chain:
*** Issued to: Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
*** Issued by: Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
*** Expires:   8/2/2028 7:59:59 PM
*** SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    Issued to: VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2009-2 CA
    Issued by: Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
    Expires:   5/20/2019 7:59:59 PM
    SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

        Issued to: My Corp
        Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2009-2 CA
        Expires:   9/10/2013 8:59:59 PM
        SHA1 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Hi, you asked this question a long time ago, but i wonder if you still dealing with signing driver for Microsoft windows 10. I'm having some troubles following the formal documentation that has many missing details. perhaps you can refer my question here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660(v=vs.85).aspx. thanks

Comment: Sorry but this was at least a job ago.  The answers below might help. The whole process was tricky. Perhaps the latest ide has a built in option from which you can extract the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, I can install the cross-sign cert from verisign that matches my cert into a cert store and signtool will automatically use it.  However, this can lead to the wrong cert being used to cross sign.

Being explicit is better

- Install my cert in the trustedpublisher store for the user that signs via certmgr.msc
- Obtain the right cert for your cert (https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5820)
- Be explicit when signing

`SignTool.exe sign /v /s trustedpublisher /ac path-to-retrieved-cert\MSCV-VSClass3.cer /n myCertName /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll driver-file-to-sign`

- Verify

`SignTool.exe verify /kp /v drive-file-to-check`

or if you have a catalog file

`SignTool.exe verify /kp /v /c driver-cat-file.cat drive-sys-file.sys`

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @cxxl sorrt about that.  So usually a cert vendor provides an intermediate cert used in cross signing.  You can check with the issuer of the cert in question and they'll have docs

Answer (score 0):

We compared two build systems and we found an additional Class 3 Public Primary cert in our certmgr trusted publishers list on the bad system.  This matched with the top level in our chain.  We disabled this publish and the top of the chain was restored to microsoft.

So, we still have questions but this appears to have resolved our problem with no ill effects to other builds.